# Perforce jenkins: How to run a build with shelved changelist?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

In the source code management option for perforce, I cannot see an option to trigger a build from a specific changelist. Is it possible to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution accidentally. The option is available as build step and **not** under source management:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to the solution by [@catchingUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458858/catchingup) there's also the possibility
to trigger a build using the "Build Review" action point (can be found on the jobs' main page right above the Build History).

In order to run the build based on a shelved change you need to enter:
**review:** the shelved change number 
**change:** the committed change number on that you want to add the shelve (probably it's the last committed change)
**status:** the string "shelved"

I think that feature is meant to be triggered automatically by a trigger script in order to verify that a change does not break anything before finally committing it.